# Rotational Animation by Linear Combination of Transformation Matrices leads to Zoom-In-Zoom-Out

Tags: javascript, animation, matrix, transform

I have a 3x3 matrix (startMatrix), which represents the actual view of an image (translation, rotation and scale). Now I create a new matrix (endMatrix) with an identitymatrix, new x- and y-coordinates,new angle and new scale like:

```
endMatrix = translate(identityMatrix, -x, -y);  
endMatrix = rotate(endMatrix, angle);  
endMatrix = scale(endMatrix, scale);
endMatrix = translate(endMatrix,(screen.width/2)/scale,screen.height/2)/scale);
```

And the functions (standard stuff)

```
function scale(m,s) {
    var n = new Matrix([
        [s, 0, 0],
        [0, s, 0],
        [0, 0, s]
    ]);
    return n.multiply(m);
}
function rotate(m, theta) {
    var n = new Matrix([
        [Math.cos(theta), -Math.sin(theta), 0],
        [Math.sin(theta), Math.cos(theta), 0],
        [0, 0, 1]
    ]);
    return n.multiply(m);
}
function translate(m, x, y) {
    var n = new Matrix([
        [1, 0, x],
        [0, 1, y],
        [0, 0, 1]
    ]);
    return n.multiply(m);
}
```

After that i transform the image with css transform matrix3d (3d only for hardware acceleration). This transform is animated with  [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

My startMatrix is for example

[image]

And The endMatrix

[image]

The linear combination looks like:

[image]

With t going from 0 to 1

The result of the linear combination of transformation matrices (the resulting image position) is correct, my problem now is: If the new angle is about 180 degree different from the actual angle, the endMatrix values change from positive to negative (or the other way around). This leads to an zoom-in zoom-out effect in the animation of the transformed image.

Is there a way to prevent this preferably with using one matrix for transforming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be problems if you interpolate matrix values directly, for very small angles the inaccuraties can not be observed but in the longer run you will face problems. Even if you normalize the matrices greater angles will make the problems visually obvious.

2D rotation is quite simple, so you can do fine without the rotation matrix approach. The best method might be to use quaternions, but the are perhaps better suited for 3D transformations.

The steps to take are:

1. Calculate the rotation, scale and transform values. If you already have these, you can skip this step. It might be easiest to keep these values separate for 2D matrix transforms.
2. Then applly interpolation to those values
3. Construct a new matrix based on the calculations

In the beginning of the animation you have to calculate values from step 1 once and then apply steps 2 and 3 at each frame.

**Step 1: get the rotation, scale, transform**

Assume the start Matrix is S and end Matrix is E.

The transformation values are simply the last columns of the, for example

```
var start_tx = S[0][2];
var start_ty = S[1][2];
var end_tx = E[0][2];
var end_ty = E[1][2];
```

The Scale for non-skewing 2D matrix is simply length of either one the base vectors in the space the matrix is spanning, for example

```
// scale is just the length of the rotation matrixes vector
var startScale = Math.sqrt( S[0][0]*S[0][0] + S[1][0]*S[1][0]);
var endScale = Math.sqrt( E[0][0]*E[0][0] + E[1][0]*E[1][0]);
```

The hardest part is to get the rotation values for the matrix. The good thing is that it only has to be calculated once per interpolation.

The rotation angle for two 2D matrixes can be calculated based on the angle between the vectors the matrixes columns are creating. If there is no rotation, the first column has values (1,0) which represents the x-axis and second column has values (0,1) which represents the y-axis.

Generally the x-axis position for Matrix S is represented by

> (S[0][0], S[0][1])

And the y-axis is pointing to direction

> (S[1][0], S[1][1])

And the same for any 2D 3x3 matrix, like E.

Using this information you can determine the rotation angle between the two matrices using only standard vector mathematics - if we assume there is no skewing.

```
// normalize column vectors
var s00 = S[0][0]/ startScale;  // x-component
var s01 = S[0][1]/ startScale;  // y-component
var e00 = E[0][0]/ endScale;    // x-component
var e01 = E[0][1]/ endScale;    // y-component
// calculate dot product which is the cos of the angle
var dp_start   = s00*1 + s01*0;     // base rotation, dot prod against x-axis
var dp_between = s00*e00 + s01*e01; // between matrices
var startRotation  = Math.acos( dp_start );
var deltaRotation  = Math.acos( dp_between );

// if detect clockwise rotation, the y -comp of x-axis < 0
if(S[0][1]<0) startRotation = -1*startRotation;

// for the delta rotation calculate cross product
var cp_between = s00*e01 - s01*e00;
if(cp_between<0) deltaRotation = deltaRotation*-1;

var endRotation = startRotation + deltaRotation;
```

Here the **startRotation** is calculated just from *acos* of the first value of the matrix. However, the second columns first value, which is **-sin(angle)** is greater than zero then the matrix has been rotated clockwise and angle must be then negative. This has to be done because acos gives only positive values.

Another way to think of that would be consider cross product s00*e01 - s01*e00 where start position (s00,s01) is x axis, where s00 == 1 and s01 == 0 and the end (e00, e01) is the ( S[0][0], S[0][1] ) creating cross product

> ```
>  1 * S[0][1] - 0 * S[0][0]
> ```

Which is S[0][1]. If that value is negative, the x-axis has been turned to clockwise direction.

For the **endRotation** we need the delta rotation from S to E. This can be calculated similarly from the dot product between the vectors the matrix is spanning. Similarly, we test for cross-product to see if the rotation direction is clockwise (negative angle).

**Step 2: interpolate**

During animation getting new values is trivial interpolation:

```
var scale = startScale + t*(endScale-startScale);
var rotation = startRotation + t*(endRotation-startRotation);
var tx = start_tx + t*(end_tx-start_tx);
var ty = start_ty + t*(end_ty-start_ty);
```

**Step 3 construct the matrix**

For each frame construct the final matrix you only have to place the values into the transformation matrix matrix

```
var cs = Math.cos(rotation);
var sn = Math.sin(rotation);
var matrix_values = [[scale*cs, -scale*sn, tx], [scale*sn, scale*cs, ty], [0,0,1]]
```

And then you have a 2D matrix which is easy to feed for any 3D hardware accelerator as well.

DISCLAIMER: some of the code has been tested, some of it has not been tested, so errors can most likely be found.

Comment: This was the first answer that gave us the right hint: preserving scale cannot be done with a sole linear combination. It was also the solution to our problem, so I will reward the bounty to you. But it brought a new problem: the rotation center is arbitrarily and not controllable. To handle this, we used a tweak of @miks solution. We now calculate a rotation center for every animation step and by that we build a matrix for every t.

Comment: Thanks. Adjusting matrices for preserving rotation center for different transformation spaces can be sometimes a slightly mind-bending task... glad you made it!

Comment: @JulianHabekost in my solution I first tried to merge all transformations except rotation into a matrix (in fact two of them: one before and one after rotation), but it seemed too complicated to me; then I edited my answer. If you click on "edited..." you will see the first variant.

Answer (score 3):

When an animated rotation preserves scale, the points do not move along straight lines, but along circles. As a result, an intermediate matrix is not a linear combination of start and end matrices. The simplest way to overcome this is to calculate all transformations during each animation frame:

```
scale = startScale*(1-t)+endScale*t;
transformMatrix = translate(identityMatrix, -startX*(1-t)-endX*t, -startY*(1-t)-endY*t);  
transformMatrix = rotate(transformMatrix, startAngle*(1-t)+endAngle*t);  
transformMatrix = scale(transformMatrix, scale);
transformMatrix = translate(transformMatrix,screen.width/2/scale,screen.height/2/scale);
```

Comment: This answer assumes you know also start values for x, y, angle and scale. If you know only the matrix, see @Tero Tolonen answer.

Comment: @Teron Tolons answer solved our problem, so I awarded him the bounty. Though it opened up new problem, the lack of controll of the rotation center. We could derive the solution therefor from this answer, calculating a "rail" on which the rotation center lies for every t.

Comment: @JulianHabekost In general it would not be possible to guess the rotation center path having only the matrices. A rotation combined with translation is in fact a rotation around another center, so the matrix loose information about original rotation center when you do translations.

Answer (score 2):

Using JavaScript to calculate transformations is effectively bypassing one of the core functions of hardware acceleration. Using CSS for the transformations is significantly more efficient.

It is not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve with this technique, but this approach might help. I use this to create tween arrays for matrix transformations.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.get3dMatrixArray = function () {
    var st = window.getComputedStyle(this, null),
        mx = (st.getPropertyValue("transform") || st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") || st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") || st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") || st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") || 'none').replace(/\(|\)| |"/g, ''),
         arr = [];
    if (mx.indexOf('matrix3d') > -1) {
        arr = mx.replace('matrix3d', '').split(',');
    } else if (mx.indexOf('matrix') > -1) {
        arr = mx.replace('matrix', '').split(',');
        arr.push(0, 1);
        [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11].map(function (i) {
            arr.splice(i, 0, 0);
        });
    } else return mx;
    return arr.map(function (v) {
        return parseFloat(v)
    });
};

HTMLElement.prototype.set3dMatrix = function (mx) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(mx) === '[object Array]')
        this.style.webkitTransform = this.style.msTransform = this.style.MozTransform = this.style.OTransform = this.style.transform = 'matrix3d(' + mx.join(",") + ')';
    return this;
};

HTMLElement.prototype.matrixTweenArray = function (endEl, steps) {
    function _tween(b, a, e) {
        b = b.get3dMatrixArray();
        var f = a.get3dMatrixArray();
        a = [];
        for (var c = 1; c < e + 1; c++) {
            var d = -1;
            a.push(b.map(function (v) {
                d++;
                return v != f[d] ? v - (v - f[d]) / e * c : v;
            }));
        }
        return a;
    }

    return _tween(this, endEl, steps);
};

HTMLElement.prototype.matrixAnimmate = function (matrixArr) {
    var that = this,
        pointer = 0;

    function _frameloop() {
        that.set3dMatrix(matrixArr[pointer]);
        pointer++;
        pointer === matrixArr.length && (pointer = 0);
        requestAnimationFrame(_frameloop);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(_frameloop)
};
```

To impliment this simply create a elements for start and end positions, and the element you want to follow the tween path.

```
<div id="start"></div>
<div id="end"></div>
<div id="animateMe"></div>
```

Add any `transform` rule to #start and to #end using css. Set css rule `display:none` if you want them hidden.

Then you can visualize the result using:

```
//build transform array - 60 frames
var mxArr = document.getElementById('start').matrixTweenArray(document.getElementById('end'), 60);
```

And call the animate function using :

```
document.getElementById('animateMe').matrixAnimmate(mxArr);
```

Dont forget to set `perspective-origin` on the div's and `perspective` on their parent element.

https://jsfiddle.net/tnt1/wjunsj36/2/

Hope this helps )

Comment: But as far as I can see, this will not solve the main problem of changing scale during rotation.

Comment: @mik you can apply any css transformation so there should be no problem )

Comment: Interesting solution, but this https://jsfiddle.net/s6xjjdmn/ shows its not the solution for my problem

Answer (score -1):

The rotation-matrix in your example has the domain [-180°,180°]. Degrees higher than 180° are outside of the functions domain.

You can map your rotation-angle to the correct domain by:

```
function MapToDomain(theta){
/* mapping abitraty rotation-angle to [0,2*PI] */
var beta = theta % (2*Math.PI);

/* mapping [0,2*PI] -> [-PI,PI] */
if (beta > (Math.PI/2) ) { beta = Math.PI/2-beta; }

return beta;
}
```

This function must be called before evaluating the matrix-elements in the rotation-function:

```
function rotate(m, theta) {
var beta = MapToDomain(theta);
var n = new Matrix([
    [Math.cos(beta), -Math.sin(beta), 0],
    [Math.sin(beta), Math.cos(beta), 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
]);
return n.multiply(m);
}
```

note: I am no java-script programmer. I hope the syntax is correct.

Comment: The syntax is right but it was no solution to the problem. A animation preserving scale sole with matrix linear combination is not possible in every case, as other answers explain.